# Is there any easier way to assign only hour and minute from one NSDate A to NSDate B, but keep B's Year Month and Day

Tags: ios, nsdate

Is there any easier way to assign only hour and minute from one NSDate A to NSDate B, but keep B's Year Month and Day?

Comment: Yeah `NSDate #1 -> NSDateComponents -> modify -> NSDate #2`.

Comment: Easier then what exactly?  What are you currently doing?

Comment: Thanks guys, i was trying to avoid NSDate #1 -> NSDateComponents -> modify -> NSDate #2   loool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know If it's an easier way, but it's the correct way:

```
NSDate *dateA = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSUInteger timeComps = (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit);
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:timeComps fromDate:dateA];
[components setHour: 3];
[components setMinute: 42];

NSDate *newDateB = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit *dateComponent = (NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit);

NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar components:dateComponent fromDate:dateA];
NSInteger day = components1.day;
NSInteger month = components1.month;
NSInteger year = components1.year;

NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar components:dateComponent fromDate:dateB];
NSInteger hour = components2.hour;
NSInteger minute = components2.minute;
NSInteger second = components2.second;

NSDateComponents *requiredComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
requiredComponent.day = day;
requiredComponent.month = month;
requiredComponent.year = year;
requiredComponent.hour = hour;
requiredComponent.minute = minute;
requiredComponent.second = second;

NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:requiredComponent];
```